# Undefined JSONP Cross Domain

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, pdo, slim

I have an API based on Php Slim Framework and want to generate JSONP for my website. When I call the website on: 'http://api.mangayurdu.com/users?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'. It returns a blank page with JSON CALLBACK() write on it. When logged to the console it is undefined.

API's index.php:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->contentType('application/json');
$app->get('/users', 'getUsers');
$app->run();

function getConnection() {
$dbhost="localhost";
$dbuser="";
$dbpass="";
$dbname="";
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;mysql:charset=utf8mb4", $dbuser, $dbpass);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

return $dbh;
}

function getUsers() {
$sql = "select * FROM manga";
try {
    $db = getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $db = null;
    echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($users).')';
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($e->getMessage()).')';
}
}
```

Javascript:

```
.factory('MY', function($http){
var fax= {};
var url = 'http://api.mangayurdu.com/users?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
fax.isimler = $http.jsonp(url);
return fax;
})

.controller('indexCtrl', function($scope, MY) {
 MY.isimler.success(function(alHemen){
      $scope.mangas = alHemen;
 });  
})
```

[image]

Comment: @JamesThorpe — "Its a blank page with JSON CALLBACK() write on it." — The argument to the callback function is undefined.

Comment: @Quentin So my users variable is empty? Its not connecting to database?

Comment: @Nasuh — No idea. I haven't used PHP since before PDO was added to it. I've no idea how it reacts to connection failures.

Comment: check url being used in dev tools network

Comment: @charlietfl — The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) says that you should put JSON_CALLBACK in the URL as a placeholder. The URL is not the problem (at the very least, it isn't the first problem). The problem is that no data from the database is in the output.

Comment: You can test that by looking directly at that URL without involving the JavaScript.

Comment: @charlietfl — You should if you are testing the URL directly so you can test it independently of the JS.

Comment: @ I add a image from network.

Comment: but now i see that it is printing that when OP accessit directly..my bad

Comment: What is type of `$users` ... it's definitely not what you want it to be...do a dump instead

Comment: @Nasuh this question here seems to be a detailed version of this [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014818/jsonp-data-provider-in-php-api), right? Please delete the other one.

Comment: I tried your code and it works on my machine. Can you also show the content of `Response` tab?

Comment: @Davide Pastore `angular.callbacks._0()`

Answer (score 0):

Don't serve it as `application/json`. Serve it as `application/javascript`. JSONP needs to be executed.

Also it appears with Slim you shouldn't use `echo`. Try calling `$app->response->setBody`.

Comment: While that is a useful comment, it has nothing to do with the problem of PHP not outputting any data in `encode_json`.

Comment: The use of `echo` can't be the problem. If it was, it wouldn't output `JSON_CALLBACK()`